# How can I change the commit a remote-tracking branch points to?

Tags: git, github

I've a remote-tracking branch called `appsec/master` that I'd like to set to `HEAD`. I normally use `git branch -f <branch> <commit>` to set a local branch, but executing `branch branch -f appsec/master HEAD` results in a new local branch `appsec/master` being created.

How can I explicitly set a remote-tracking branch before executing `git push -f -u <upstream> <branch>`?

```
(master %<>)$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all -n 25
* 211e9d7 (HEAD -> master) Working version of scanner
| * c5a9ec4 (appsec/master) Added regex.json
|/
...
```

**NB**: I know this question is a bit synthetic, since I should never do a `git push -f` or modify remote-tracking branches manually, but in this case I use my own repository with no colloboration peers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "set" remote-tracking branches, they are by design images of what's been fetched from the remote last time you checked it.

However, you can set whatever ref on a local branch then force-push it to the remote. Then, simply fetching from it will update your remote-tracking branch as well.

Comment: I found that a `git fetch` is not necessary to update the remote-tracking branch. It's updated automatically by `git push -f`.

Answer (score 1):

Your remote branches on local machine are also represented, but by default they are hidden. You could see the list of them with `git branch --all`.
So, even If you have no internet connection, you could merge remote branch (which is cached locally).
Thus, you can simply run `git push --force appsec master`.
And then run `git fetch` to receive all changes from server into your local remote branches.
See [git remote branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any pushes or pulls by using [`git update-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref):

```bash
git update-ref refs/remotes/REMOTE_NAME/BRANCH_NAME NEW_COMMIT OLD_COMMIT
```

`git update-ref` will verify for you that `ORIGIN_NAME/BRANCH_NAME` indeed points to `OLD_COMMIT` before updating it to `NEW_COMMIT`. If you don't want this verification, you can omit `OLD_COMMIT`.

In the question, it would be `git update-ref refs/remotes/appsec/master HEAD`.

You can list all refs by using [`git show-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref).